# why am i getting this error in Firebase "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value"

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

i get this error in my firebase backend Nodejs code "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value" 
Here is the Code that is being ran;

```
exports.payOnDelivery = functions.database.ref('/CompletedJobs/{id}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
let chargeID = snapshot.child("chargeID/id").val();
let amount = +(snapshot.child("chargeID/amount").val());
let amountAfterCut = amount*0.75;
let emailHash = snapshot.child("jobTaker").val();
if (chargeID == null || amount == null || emailHash == null){
    console.log("Could not parse data");
    return 1;
}
console.log("This is Before Observe");
console.log('Blah blah:', chargeID, amount, emailHash);
admin.database().ref(`Couriers/${emailHash}`).once('value').then(function(userSnapshot){
    const accountID = userSnapshot.child("stripeAccount/id");
    console.log("AcctID:",accountID);
    stripe.transfers.create({
        amount: amountAfterCut,
        currency: "cad",
        source_transaction: chargeID,
        destination: accountID
    }), function(err, transfer){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            console.log("Transfer made",transfer);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}, function(error){
    console.error(error);
});
});
```

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to take some time to learn about how promises work with Cloud Functions.  Please see the documentation and the embedded video series on that page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the Promise from the database query.

Change:

```
admin.database().ref(`Couriers/${emailHash}`).once('value')...
```

to:

```
return admin.database().ref(`Couriers/${emailHash}`).once('value')....
```

**Update:**

As comments indicate,this answer doesn't address all the issues.  I'm not proficient with Stripe.  Hopefully, someones else will provide a better answer.  Try looking at the [sample code here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js).

Comment: That's not enough - there's embedded async work inside the `then` callback.

Comment: i tried the return version and that seems to get rid of the error msg but doesnt call the rest of the code inside the then callback